# $L^1$ and $L^2$ norms for difference of bounded vectors

Tags: vectors

Suppose that $x$ and $x^\prime$ are two $n$-dimensional vectors. In general, we know that: $$\Vert x - x^\prime \Vert \le \sqrt{n}~\Vert x - x^\prime \Vert_2$$
Is there a tighter bound to compare the $L^1$ and $L^2$ norms of the difference if we have $\Vert x \Vert = \Vert x' \Vert = 1$?

Comment: Could you please define $\|\cdot\|$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked if there is constant $k \leq \sqrt{n}$ such that $\|x - x'\|_1 \leq k \| x- x'\|_2$. This is equivalent to find the greatest constant $C \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ such that

$$ \frac{\| x- x' \|_2}{\| x - x'\|_1} \geq C,\quad \forall x,x': \|x\|_1 = \|x'\|_1 =1 $$

The answer is no because $x' = - x = (\frac{1}{n},...,\frac{(-1)^n}{n})$ satisfying $\| x\|_1 = \| x' \|_1 = 1$ and $\frac{\| x- x' \|_2}{\| x - x'\|_1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $